# How to get numbers from two objects and add them in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to make an add function but it's too hard.
I  get 2 numbers from an object and add them, how do I do that?

My code:

```scala
def add(a: Object, b: Object): Object = ???
sealed abstract class Object
case class Number(num: Int) extends Object
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pattern matching to 1) insure that both args are type  `Number` (not some other sub-type of `Object`), and 2) extract the `Int` from each `Number` so that they can be combined in the result `Number`.

```
def add(a: Object, b: Object): Object = (a,b) match {
  case (Number(x), Number(y)) => Number(x+y)
  case _ => throw new Error("not implemented yet")
}
```